# How to detect method signatures of imported python modules

Tags: python, python-importlib

I have a python app which can load and run extensions.  It looks like this:

```
import importlib, sys

sys.path.append('.')

module = importlib.import_module( 'extension' )
Extension = getattr(module, 'Extension')
instance = Extension()

instance.FunctionCall(arg1='foo')
```

The users can create their own loadable extension by implementing a class I defined.  In this case, it is in `extension.py`:

```
class Extension:
    def FunctionCall(self, arg1):
        print(arg1)
```

This works great for now, but I would like to extend my interface to pass another argument into `Extension.FunctionCall`

```
instance.FunctionCall(arg1='foo', arg2='bar')
```

How can I do this while maintaining reverse compatibility with the existing interface?

---

Here's what happens to existing users if I make the change:

```
$ python3 loader.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "loader.py", line 9, in <module>
    instance.FunctionCall(arg1='foo', arg2='bar')
TypeError: FunctionCall() got an unexpected keyword argument 'arg2'
```

---

One option is to catch the `TypeError`, but is this the best solution?  It looks like it could get unmaintainable with several iterations of interfaces.

```
try:
    instance.FunctionCall(arg1='foo', arg2='bar')
except TypeError:
    instance.FunctionCall(arg1='foo')
```

Another option is to define the "interface version" as a property of the extension and then use that in a case statement, but it would be nicer to simply detect what is supported instead of pushing overhead to the users.

```
if hasattr(Extension, 'Standard') and callable(getattr(Extension, 'Standard')):
    standard=instance.Standard()
else:
    standard=0

if standard == 0:
    instance.FunctionCall(arg1='foo')
elif standard == 1:
    instance.FunctionCall(arg1='foo', arg2='bar')
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with importlib. All importlib does is, well, import module (with various hooks for finding or manipulating them beforehand).

The issue here is plain API versioning / evolution: you defined an API in such a way that it can't be evolved, now you're trying to evolve it.

Comment: The first option is basically "a mess" (can be done using try/expect or by introspecting using `inspect.signature`, in both cases this is pretty fiddly and prone to failure in the face of common CPython optimisation tricks (e.g. using default parameters to optimise loading, using `*args` to ignore parameters you don't care about, ...). The second option is "API versioning", where the user simply opts into whichever version / revision of the API they want, this puts a heavier burden on them but allows everyone to know precisely where they stand.

Comment: A third option is to update the API (this'll require a break regardless) such that it is more evolvable in the future e.g. require that consumers take `**kwargs` (possibly pass randomly generated attribute names while at it to ensure they do, or verify it using `inspect.signature`). This is a bit limited (to e.g. adding parameters), but means you can add any new information you want. Of course that assumes the code can still make sense if the parameter is ignored, so that can only be used to give more precision or opportunities / flexibility to the callee.

Comment: Anyway regardless this is really more about API design (and evolveability thereof), and really opinion-based rather than anything which can be replied to objectively.

Comment: Great, I didn't know about `inspect.signature`,  I think this is the method I'll go with.